# PHP Get current files directory

Tags: php, directory, split

I am wondering if it is possible to get the full path to a file it's echoed from then maybe split it

So like:
echo $currentDir
//output EX: /home/user/public_html/scrips/code/test/ha

then split it 3 directory's down so the output is: /home/user/public_html/scripts

Is this possible?

Comment: You should say three directories **up** instead of down.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the directory the file is currently executing in with `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` in < PHP 5.3.

You can take a path and go up a few levels with string manipulation.

```
$path = implode(
    DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 
    array_slice(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path),0,-3)
);
```

Alternatively, this *should* work...

```
$path = realpath(
    rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . str_repeat('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 3)
);
```

Though the path may be transformed to a different string via `realpath()` (though it *will* point to the same location).

Comment: Sorry Alex, your spacing was wonky-jawed.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for fixing it. I'm typing this on a laptop upon a tissue box that's about to run out of battery.

Comment: One more question, how can I also split the final result to just output: scripts ? thanks

Comment: @MicMac Examine the results of exploding it on the directory separator. It should then be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is :

1. Create a class for the file type;
2. Define some constants of the main folders for my project, so it makes my life easier;
3. Make a method inside that class to retrieve the path;
4. Assign the result of the function to properties, also makes my life easier;

Such as:

```
class Image {
   private $temp_path;
   protected $upload_dir = 'imagens';

   public function directory() {
       return $this->upload_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->filename;
   }
}

// If you want only the extension:

private function _ext() {
    return strrchr($this->filename, ".");
}
```

Of course there is much more to the class, MUCH more , but thats what you need to retrieve the path of the uploaded file. All you gotta do is set the properties straight in the file upload page using object oriented PhP to pass them to the class , so it can even be stored in your DB for better record and control of your files and their properties.

If you need more info on the whole thing just ask.

Best of luck to you.